# install4j - Where is the current version of application stored?

Tags: install4j, auto-update

Our RCP application employs intall4j for installation. Our customer asked us that the installer should not write any entries into registry. For this **we removed the action "Register Add/Remove item" from our installation steps**.
However post this whenever auto update tries to install update before application launch, the installer gets into an infinite loop where post auto update the update is again getting trigged. We think this is because the auto update installer has not updated the current version of application and hence even after update, the launcher keeps relaunching auto-updater again.
Does this mean the current version of application installed by install4j comes from Registry. Is it possible to change this?

@Ingo,
I have enabled the logs. PFB the logs for autoupdater:

```
sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
[INFO] Variable changed: sys.resolveUserSpecificInstallationDir=true[class java.lang.String]
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction [ID 1337]: Execute action
       Property rollbackScript: null
       Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_12
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Execute action successful after 15 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.LoadResponseFileAction [ID 1338]: Execute action
       Property excludedVariables: null
       Property file: null
       Property overwriteStrategy: Do not overwrite command line
       Property registerForResponseFile: true
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Variable changed: sys.adminRights=false[class java.lang.Boolean]
       Variable changed: sys.languageId=de[class java.lang.String]
       Variable changed: guiws_url=https://flexprod.telekom.de/guisrv/services/[class java.lang.String]
       Variable changed: updates_fullurl=http://qde1y9.de.t-internal.com/rcp/prod_test/updates.xml[class java.lang.String]
       Variable changed: sys.installationDir=C:\Users\cts02\AppData\Local\FxPRCPGuiClient\FlexProd_prod[class java.lang.String]
       Variable changed: sys.component.423=true[class java.lang.Boolean]
       Variable changed: sys.component.400=true[class java.lang.Boolean]
       Execute action successful after 0 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.update.CheckForUpdateAction [ID 1339]: Execute action
       Property connectTimeout: 10000
       Property connectionFailureScript: null
       Property readTimeout: 20000
       Property requestHeaders: []
       Property url: http://qde1y9.de.t-internal.com/rcp/prod_test/updates.xml
       Property variable: updateDescriptor
       Property acceptAllCertificates: false
       Property askForProxy: true
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Property showError: true
       Download: http://qde1y9.de.t-internal.com/rcp/prod_test/updates.xml to C:\Users\cts02\AppData\Local\Temp\518\i4jupd8246635060036627292.xml; size: 483 bytes
       Variable changed: updateDescriptor=com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.update.UpdateDescriptorImpl@327471b5[class com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.update.UpdateDescriptorImpl]
       Execute action successful after 313 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction [ID 1437]: Execute action
       Property rollbackScript: null
       Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_13
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Current Version during Updatecheck = 7.100.11.03
       upDesc = com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.update.UpdateDescriptorImpl@327471b5
       New Version during Updatecheck = 7.200.00.41
       isUpdateRequired = true
       Variable changed: isUpdateRequired=true[class java.lang.Boolean]
       Execute action successful after 0 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.SetVariableAction [ID 1340]: Execute action
       Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_14
       Property variableName: updateDescriptorEntry
       Property failIfNull: true
       Property onlyIfUndefined: false
       Property responseFileVariable: false
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Variable changed: updateDescriptorEntry=UpdateDescriptorEntry [target: 689, file: FlexProd_64Bit.exe][class com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.update.UpdateDescriptorEntryImpl]
       Execute action successful after 0 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.SetVariableAction [ID 1342]: Execute action
       Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_16
       Property variableName: updaterNewVersion
       Property failIfNull: false
       Property onlyIfUndefined: false
       Property responseFileVariable: false
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Variable changed: updaterNewVersion=7.200.00.41[class java.lang.String]
       Execute action successful after 0 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.SetVariableAction [ID 1343]: Execute action
       Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_17
       Property variableName: updaterDownloadUrl
       Property failIfNull: false
       Property onlyIfUndefined: false
       Property responseFileVariable: false
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Variable changed: updaterDownloadUrl=http://qde1y9.de.t-internal.com/rcp/prod_test/FlexProd_64Bit.exe[class java.lang.String]
       Execute action successful after 0 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.SetVariableAction [ID 1344]: Execute action
       Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_18
       Property variableName: updaterDownloadFile
       Property failIfNull: false
       Property onlyIfUndefined: false
       Property responseFileVariable: false
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Variable changed: updaterDownloadFile=C:\Users\cts02\AppData\Local\install4j\update\RmxleFByb2Q=\JdUUEq0txyEdauSNfbR1Vm8987g=\FlexProd_64Bit.exe[class java.lang.String]
       Execute action successful after 16 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.net.DownloadFileAction [ID 1345]: Execute action
       Property connectTimeout: 10000
       Property connectionFailureScript: null
       Property digestAlgorithm: SHA-256
       Property digestUrl: 
       Property readTimeout: 20000
       Property requestHeaders: []
       Property targetFile: C:\Users\cts02\AppData\Local\install4j\update\RmxleFByb2Q=\JdUUEq0txyEdauSNfbR1Vm8987g=\FlexProd_64Bit.exe
       Property url: http://qde1y9.de.t-internal.com/rcp/prod_test/FlexProd_64Bit.exe
       Property acceptAllCertificates: false
       Property askForProxy: true
       Property checkDigest: false
       Property deleteOnExit: false
       Property dontAskForRetry: false
       Property retryIfInterrupted: true
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Property showError: true
       Property showFileName: true
       Property showProgress: true
       Download: http://qde1y9.de.t-internal.com/rcp/prod_test/FlexProd_64Bit.exe to C:\Users\cts02\AppData\Local\install4j\update\RmxleFByb2Q=\JdUUEq0txyEdauSNfbR1Vm8987g=\FlexProd_64Bit.exe; size: 116123648 bytes
       Execute action successful after 3987 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.SetModeAction [ID 1347]: Execute action
       Property directoryFilter: null
       Property fileFilter: null
       Property fileTarget: everything
       Property files: [C:\Users\cts02\AppData\Local\install4j\update\RmxleFByb2Q=\JdUUEq0txyEdauSNfbR1Vm8987g=\FlexProd_64Bit.exe]
       Property filesRoot: null
       Property mode: 755
       Property recursive: false
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Property showFileNames: true
       Property showProgress: false
       Execute action successful after 0 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.update.ScheduleUpdateAction [ID 1348]: Execute action
       Property arguments: null
       Property installerFile: C:\Users\cts02\AppData\Local\install4j\update\RmxleFByb2Q=\JdUUEq0txyEdauSNfbR1Vm8987g=\FlexProd_64Bit.exe
       Property maxCancelCount: 10
       Property maxTries: 3
       Property version: 7.200.00.41
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Execute action successful after 47 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction [ID 1349]: Execute action
       Property rollbackScript: null
       Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_20
       Property rollbackSupported: false
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction [ID 1349]: no shutdown file property
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction [ID 1349]: execute directly
       cleaning up
       Finished
```

*I checked i4jparams.conf file post the bgupdater execution. The version represented by "sys.version" is still pointing to old version.*

Comment: The version is not stored in the registry, but in `<installation directory>/.install4j/i4jparams.conf`. Start the update downloader with the argument `-Dinstall4j.log=<path to writable log file>` then you can see why it downloads the update again.

Comment: @IngoKegel, I have updated the logs above. Post running my updater i could see that the version in the conf file is still the same.

Comment: I can also see error "com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction [ID 1349]: no shutdown file property" . I have started bgupdater immediately with script using 'UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(Arrays.asList("-q", "-splash", "Updating ..."), true, null);'

Comment: Are you sure that the downloaded installer is actually executed? Is the file `<installation directory>/.install4j/i4jpara,s.com` updated? Also, is the downloaded installer a regular installer and not an "Add-on" installer?

Comment: Yes I have manually executed the bgupdater.exe that is found in the .install4j folder. No the params file was not updated at all. It is a regular installer and not an add on installer

Comment: But the bgupdater downloads an installer file that is not immediately executed, how do you make sure that the downloaded installer was actually executed but has not updated the installed version? The mentioned installation log should be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The problem within my installer itself. During update installation the update installer was actually installing the application in different location because during update there was additional instruction to set installation directory using context.setInstalltionDirectory.
Because of this the installation itself went into infinite loop. Once I removed this unneceassary step the problem got rectified.
Thanks.